# Exam solution ignores boundaries and prints over frame

Tags: hyphenation, exam

In a document with the exam class and `\printanswers`, the borders of the solution are ignored and the frame is being printed over.

How could I fix this? (dropping the `\extrawidth` did not fix the problem, but it's better visible that way)

MWE:
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\extrawidth{-1cm}
\printanswers

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{question}
\begin{parts}

\part Blah
\begin{solution}
    für 2NF: Aufteilen des Relationenschemas, so dass die gefundenen Teilabhängigkeiten nicht mehr auftreten können:
\end{solution}

\end{parts}
\end{question}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try adding a few discretionary hyphens to "Teilabhängigkeiten".

Comment: @barbara That would work around this example case, but not for all of the others. I was hoping for a more automated way, too :-)

Comment: note this is unrelated to the exam class, you would see the same in any document class if setting that text.

Comment: I see it is a long word without break. But I'm trying to understand why the word is not wrapped into the next line if it doesn't fit? Just because it's long?

Comment: Tex's default settings do not allow it to over-stretch the white space that much so it gives up, complains about an over-full box in the log file and leaves it sticking out. You could allow the white space to stretch (`\sloppy`) but then the output looks pretty horrible.

Comment: AHHHHH! There was so much single-lined stuff in my real document that I didn't realize it was (by default) justified, I assumed it was left-aligned. Now this all makes sense to me. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (always)  need to specify T1 font encoding otherwise you will not get correct hyphenation for non-ascii letters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\extrawidth{-1cm}
\printanswers

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{question}
\begin{parts}

\part Blah
\begin{solution}
    für 2NF: Aufteilen des Relationenschemas, so dass die gefundenen Teilabhängigkeiten nicht mehr auftreten können:
\end{solution}

\end{parts}
\end{question}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoa, that fixes most of these problems in the document and even a lot more from my list to investigate later, thanks! :-)
Yet still I don't understand why it does not wrap a line that could easily be wrapped :-)

Comment: @hoeni  you were using the original 7bit font encoding for unaccented English, so no words can be hyphenated after an accented letter, so your text could not be wrapped as to do so without hyphenation would require over-stretching the white space.